# How do you pass an array of string through an event in an Interop User Control to vb6

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6, interop

I have a VB.net control that has an event:

```
Public Event PassNames(ByVal names() as String)
```

When the event triggered in VB6, I get the following error:

*"Function or interface marked as restriced, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic"*

Here is the event in VB6:

```
Private Sub IteropControl1_PassNames(ByVal names() As String)
      MsgBox "I don't work"
End Sub
```

**Is there a way to uses arrays with Interop User Controls?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out what I was doing wrong.

In my VB.net control, my event should be

```
Public Event PassNames(ByRef names() as String)
```

instead of

```
Public Event PassNames(ByVal names() as String)
```